# Cannot generate ADO.NET Model classes

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2012, ado.net-entity-data-model, ef-database-first

I am using **Visual Studio Express 2012 for Web**.

I have created a new empty web site using **.net framework 4**.

I am using **SQL Server 2008 R2 Service Pack 2**, and I have a database with 4 tables there.

When I try to add a new ADO.NET data model into my website from this database, the Model.edmx, Model.tt, and Model.Context.tt files are all generated, but my **Model.cs and Model.Context.cs files are missing**. If I try to use the option 'update the model from database' nothing happens.

I have installed Visual Studio just two days ago, and initially I could work with a successfully generated model for another web site. But now I cannot generate the model in any website. I have tried with other databases, to no success.

[image]

Comment: Use the Build->Transform T4 Templates command if present, otherwise, right click the .tt files and do Run Custom Tool.

Comment: Which steps did you take to create your project? I have had this issue before when I selected the wrong project type.

Comment: @JohnSaunders right clicking the tt files and doing run custom tool did the trick .... thanks a lot

Comment: @Simon I created an empty ASP.NET Website ..... then straightaway I right clicked the project in solution explorer and selected add new ADO.NET Data Model

Answer (score 4):

Thanks to John Saunders for providing this answer as a comment.

Use the Build->Transform T4 Templates command if present, otherwise, right click the .tt files and do Run Custom Tool